# optional closure property in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How do you declare an optional closure as a property in Swift?

I am using this code:

```
    var respondToButton:(sender: UIButton) -> Bool
```

but the compiler complains that the property is not initialized by the end of the initializer. I believe I can solve this issue by declaring the var as an optional, however, I can not find the correct syntax.

How do I declare this closure property as an optional?

Comment: does `var respondToButton:((sender: UIButton) -> Bool)?` work?

Comment: awesome yes it does! Add an answer so i can accept?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I believe you just need to wrap the closure type in parenthesis, like so:

```
var respondToButton:((sender: UIButton) -> Bool)?
```

---

Alternatively if this is a closure type you're going to use often you can create a [`typealias`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_539) to make it more readable:

```
typealias buttonResponder = (sender: UIButton) -> Bool
```

then in your class:

```
var respondToButton:buttonResponder?
```