# When should i use capture list in closure, and when to use weak vs. unowned?

Tags: ios, swift

i am reading a book, a method in viewcontroller:

```
func addNewWord() {
    // create our alert controller
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Add new word", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    // add two text fields, one for English and one for French
    ac.addTextField { textField in
        textField.placeholder = "English"
    }
    // ac.addTextField { (textField) in // also works.
    ac.addTextField { (textField: UITextField) in
        textField.placeholder = "French"
    }
    // create an "Add Word" button that submits the user's input
    let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Word", style: .default) {
        [unowned self, ac] (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        // pull out the English and French words, or an empty string if there was a problem
        let firstWord = ac.textFields?[0].text ?? ""
        let secondWord = ac.textFields?[1].text ?? ""
        // submit the English and French word to the insertFlashcard() method
        self.insertFlashcard(first: firstWord, second: secondWord)
    }
    // add the submit action, plus a cancel button
    ac.addAction(submitAction)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
    // present the alert controller to the user
    present(ac, animated: true)
}
```

I don't understand why `ac` doesn't need to mark `unowned`?

when is the best time to mark `unowned` or `weak`?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, `self` is a View Controller or some other semi-persistent object. View Controllers are fairly expensive memory-wise, given how much state they govern, including the view hierarchy. When a View Controller is dismissed from the App's navigation flow, its resources really need to be freed. So the design pattern is to always pay attention to `self`, so avoid excess references to the VC. For example if the closure lives on for a long time, but the VC is dismissed from navigation, the VC and its associated resources chew up memory uselessly: a memory leak.

In contrast, local variables to a function *only* have a longer life with respect to the contained closure -- their initial reference count is guaranteed to decrement as soon as the containing function exits. So the closure alone can manage references to it and not be concerned with its App-wide lifecycle.

`owned` vs. `weak` is really a different question. It depends on your App design -- there's no formulaic answer. `unowned`, like `weak`, does *not* increment the retain count of captured objects in the closure. However that leaves the possibility that the captured object ends up with a retain count of 0, and will be deallocated before the closure runs, risking a crash. So you need to be sure, if you say `unowned`, that *something else* is *always* taking ownership responsibility. In contrast, declaring `self` as `weak` acknowledges the object as volatile, and forces you to check (`if let`...) if the object was deallocated.

Also, I didn't check the related links thoroughly, but I'm sure I'm repeating a lot of what has been said before. Read the highly upvoted posts first.

[Shall we always use [unowned self] inside closure in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift?rq=1)

[optional closure property in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170217/optional-closure-property-in-swift?rq=1)

*EDIT, PERHAPS THE REAL ISSUE*

Your book's code makes no sense, because the manual specifically says:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html

> This distinction [leaving a variable out of the capture list entirely,
>   versus including it, but with no weak/unowned designation] is not
>   visible when the captured variable’s type has reference semantics. For
>   example, there are two things named x in the code below, a variable in
>   the outer scope and a constant in the inner scope, but they both refer
>   to the same object because of reference semantics.

In other words, because `ac` is a reference type object, including it "bare" in the capture list does nothing.

I believe the book is in error, and it should say `[unowned self, unowned ac]`.

My reasoning is: UIAlertController `ac` -> strong reference to `submitAction` (via `addAction`) -> strong reference to anonymous closure -> strong reference to `ac`. Unless one of those is internally declared as `weak` just for this purpose, `unowned ac` is necessary. Too bad some of that is closed source and we cannot check for sure. The documentation is not specific so we have to assume those are all stored strongly in the library code.

Comment: i know once the function leaves the resource the variables or constants should be released, but the problem is without marking `unowned` it produces strong reference. is't it?

Comment: it is like the picture in the swift programming language book. the variables and constants were released. but producing strong reference to each other. is't it?

Comment: Yes the closure otherwise has a strong reference. This is only an issue if the closure runs asynchronously, that is, after the function exits. This is not the case, for example, with `Array.map()`.

Comment: See addendum regarding your cycle comment.

Comment: Actually, I marked unowned in advance. I also feel something wrong here. So, I asked again and tried to make it more clear.

Comment: Please clarify your question then. Quote the book then put your suggested change below. A lot of rapidly published programming books are full of errors. Would be good to know which book.

Comment: But I want to see more comments to determine if it is a error. And see how people would deal with it.

Comment: Comments will be better as well as answers if you clarify the question! That can only help.

Answer (score 1):

Your text field blocks are called immediately and don't reference self or your `UIAlertController`.

The action blocks are called later (when the user clicks a button) and thus need to store references to `self` or `ac`. By storing this reference you can introduce [Circular References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934466/avoiding-circular-retention-using-arc-strong-weak-learning-some-basics) which can lead to memory leaks. Essentially if you use a strong reference to `ac` in the action block then the block points to the `UIAlertController` and the `UIAlertController` points to the block and nothing ever gets released.

Comment: Is there a way to confirm your idea? "Your text field blocks are called immediately"? Like Profiling or something?

Comment: Apple has a new memory debugger in Xcode 8. If you use it you can see circular references. Prior to Xcode 8 you could use Instruments but it was a bit of a pain.

Comment: Also your text field blocks don't reference self or ac so its not an issue.